# Resolution issue with Ubuntu 14.04.1 [Dual Boot with Windows 7]

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, resolution

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 along side my Windows 7 operating system today. My Windows Partition works perfectly fine, the GRUB menu works perfectly fine, and I've installed any updates for Ubuntu that were present after install. However I cannot get Ubuntu to display in my native resolution of 1920 x 1080. I am only given two options for resolution in the settings, 800 x 600 and 1024 x 768. My graphics card is a nVidia Geforce 750Ti that is connected to my monitor via HDMI.

I've Googled this problem extensively and ultimately decided to try and update my graphics card driver. I downloaded the correct driver from nVidia's website and followed their install instructions. However I cannot get the driver to install. When I attempt to install the graphics driver I get an error message saying I'm running an X server.

I Googled how to disable the X server and I've tried numerous commands from `killall x` to `sudo service lightdm stop`. Neither of this worked. I either receive a message stating that no instance of X is running, or in the case with stopping lightdm, my entire screen goes black and I'm unable to do anything until I reboot my computer.

Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The proprietary Nvidia drivers included in 14.04 do not support the newer GeForce 750/750Ti.

### Solution 1 (the easier one): PPA

1. Open a *terminal*
2. Add the repository with the driver version that supports the 750Ti: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
3. Update your software lists and software:

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`
4. Install one of the Nvidia drivers (e.g. -343)

   `sudo apt-get install nvidia-343`
5. Restart

This will survive a kernel update.

---

### Solution 2: Manual installation

1. Switch to *console* (I assume you simply opened gnome-terminal):

   `ctrl`+`alt`+`F1` (back to desktop with `F7`)
2. Login with your user account.
3. Stop lightdm:

   `sudo service lightdm stop`
4. Install the Nvidia driver:

   `sudo sh /path/to/installer.sh`
5. Restart lightdm:

   `sudo service lightdm start`

You may have to repeat these steps after a kernel update!

---

To change your screen resolution to FHD, check display settings, or otherwise the *Nvidia X server settings* tool.